# Ruby: Maximum Waiting time for pessimistic lock?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, locking

Two different systems/process try to update same request. However, I am using pessimistic locking mechanism: `lock!`. Suppose system-1 acquire the lock before system-2.
What is maximum waiting time for the system-2 to acquire lock? 
Related question: If it reached the maximum waiting time, will it rollback transaction?

```
Request.transaction do

  lock!
    # Do something important

end
```

Comment: Multi-tagging different versions of Rails here isn't really a great idea. ActiveRecord changed substantially between those versions, so which one are you actually using?

Comment: Is the lock wait-time configurable or not? Usually it is.